# How to populate employee name when their employee ID is entered in a textbox

Tags: excel, authentication, vba

Employee Login System using Excel with Macro.
I'm using a very simple technique of "if elseif then"

I want to display Employee Name when their ID is typed.
I used very simple code:

```
Dim CM As Boolean
Dim UserRange As Range
Dim x As Range
'EASY
Private Sub cmdClear_Click()

txtEmpID.Value = ""
txtName.Value = ""
txtEmpID.SetFocus

End Sub

Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub txtEmpID_Change()

'If txtEmpID.Value = "111" Then
'txtName.Value = "Ryan"
'
'ElseIf txtEmpID.Value = "222" Then
'txtName.Value = "Tim"
'
'End If

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_activate()

Do
If CM = True Then Exit Sub
TextBox1 = Format(Now, "hh:mm:ss")
DoEvents
Loop

Set UserRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")

For Each x In UserRange.Cells
    If x.Value = txtEmpID.Text Then

    x.Offset(1, 0) = txtName.Value
    End If


    Exit For
    Next x

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
CM = True
End Sub
```

However I want to have a sheet that holds Employee Name (column A) and ID(column B) [Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkUEy.png)
Then from there, I can add more employee names and IDs.  Also when I click on Login it will display the current time in Column C and then It will also display their time-out. Here's my main form [Main Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzMjA.png)

Thank you so much.

Comment: use cells where the row number comes from application.match.

Comment: I used this code:Set UserRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:B")

For Each x In UserRange.Cells
    If x.Value = txtEmpID.Text Then
    
    x.Offset(0, -1) = txtName.Value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand but here's my response:

Here's a way to update the field from the worksheet:

```
Private Sub txtEmpID_Change()
Dim mySheet As Worksheet
Dim myRange As Range

Set mySheet = Sheets("Emp_ID")
Set myRange = mySheet.Range("B:B").Find(txtEmpID.Value, , , xlWhole)

If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
txtName.Value = myRange.Offset(0, -1)
Else
txtName.Value = "Match not found"
End If

End Sub
```

Set that to occur whenever there's an update.

As for recording the login time: `myRange.offset(0,1) = Format(Now,"hh:mm:ss")`

How will you know / display the logout time when someone is logging in?

Comment: Thank you. Whenever I type the 1st character of empID it will display the name right away..It also gives an error whenever I type an entry which is not in the excel .

Comment: Oops, set the wrong parameter on the find function. Corrected to match entire word instead of case.

Comment: Run-time error '91':
Object variable or With block variable not set.

It hightlights this line of code:
Set myRange = mySheet.Range("B:B").Find(txtEmpID.Value, , , xlWhole).Offset(0, -1)

Comment: Made some adjustments and actually tested. Should work now.

Comment: Thank you so much..ill be back in 2days..ill keep u posted..can i ask for ur email..

Comment: Thank you so much avplol..it's now working..I'm currently working on as to how I can capture the login time..

Comment: Hi avplol, can you help me with this issue i'm currently having with  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43792983/i-wanted-to-use-listbox-so-that-i-can-select-the-entry-rather-than-textbox